# How to format the data received from apex so that it can be used by dual listbox in lightning web component

Tags: javascript, lightning-web-components

I have an LWC in which I have a dual listbox. The data returned by apex has the datatype `Map<Map<String,String>,String>`. Eg: `["{label=Created By ID, value=Contact_ID__r.CreatedById}","account"}]`.

Out of this, I extracted the part `Map<String,String>` in JS file. Eg. `["{label=Created By ID, value=Contact_ID__r.CreatedById}"]`.

This is how I did it in JS file:

```js
//result.data contains the data returned by apex method.
//Variable availableOptionsForAccountFields will be used by dual listbox to display the data.

            var iterator = 0;
            var keys = Object.keys(result.data); //store the keys.
            Object.keys(result.data).forEach(fieldToBeAddedAsAvailableOption => { //loop over the returned data.
                //Identify the object of the field and add it to respective variable so that it can be displayed to the user using dual listbox
                if (result.data[keys[iterator]] == 'account') {
                    this.availableOptionsForAccountFields.push(fieldToBeAddedAsAvailableOption);
                }
                iterator = iterator+1;
            });

//After execution of this loop, the variable availableOptionsForAccountFields will have all the values to be displayed in dual listbox.
```

HTML Code:

```html
<lightning-dual-listbox name="Account Fields" label="Account Fields"
                                source-label="Available Fields" selected-label="Selected Fields"
                                options={availableOptionsForAccountFields} value={selectedOptionsForAccountFields}>
</lightning-dual-listbox>
```

When I try to run this, I am getting an error. `aura_proddebug.js:4763 Error: [LWC error]: Invalid "key" attribute value in "<li>" in [object:vm undefined (18)] for item number 0. Set a unique "key" value on all iterated child elements.`.

I found out that the error is because I am not giving data to variable `availableOptionsForAccountFields` in proper format.

The data that I am giving has the following format:

```js
["{label=Created By ID, value=Contact_ID__r.CreatedById}"]
```

The data needs to be in the following format:

```js
[{"label":"Start Date", "value":"Contract_Start_Date__c"}]
```

I did research to find out how I can change the format of data but nothing worked. I tried to use `JSON.stringify()` and `.replace()` in various combinations but I was not able to convert the format of data. I need help. Please guide. Thank You!

### Updates

Apex code:

```
public static Map<Map<String,String>,String> getFields(List<SelectOption> availableFields,String objectName){
        
        Map<Map<String,String>,String> listOfMapToBeReturned = new Map<Map<String,String>,String>();
        
        //Loop through available fields and insert all the fields and values into a map because lightning does not support SelectOption
        for(SelectOption selectOptionItem : availableFields){
            
            //This map will hold the label and value from SelectOption
            Map<Map<String,String>,String> mapToBeAddedToListOfMap = new Map<Map<String,String>,String>();  
           
            //Insert field label and it's value into the map
            mapToBeAddedToListOfMap.put('label',selectOptionItem.getLabel());
            mapToBeAddedToListOfMap.put('value',selectOptionItem.getValue());
            listOfMapToBeReturned.put(mapToBeAddedToListOfMap,objectName);
        }
        
        return listOfMapToBeReturned;
        
    }
```

Comment: Rather than creating a Map like this: `Map<Map<String,String>,String>` create as follows: `Map<String,Map<String,String>>`. To extract the items from the map and prepare the dataset for UI control, you can refer my blog post: http://santanuboral.blogspot.com/2019/09/LWC-dynamic-Datatable.html

Comment: @SantanuBoral Thanks for responding. In `Map<Key,Value>`, the key needs to be unique. This is the reason I have used `Map<Map<String,String>,String>` instead of `Map<String,Map<String,String>>`.

Comment: can you update the apex code here?

Comment: @rahulgawale I have made some changes to the code and hence I have asked another question. I have added the apex code too. Please check it. Thanks! 

https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/311788/how-to-format-the-data-received-from-apex-so-that-it-can-be-used-by-dual-listbox

Comment: @Koustubh can you please add those details here instead of a new question. you should go with a new question only if its literally different questions.

Comment: Is there any particular reason you want to keep a map as key of another map? @Koustubh

Comment: @rahulgawale I have added apex code in the question. Here is the reason why I want to keep a map as key of another map. I have to a add field and name of the object from which that field belongs into a data structure. I chose to use a map. I cannot add the name of the object as the key because then it won't be unique. Thank you...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/110270/discussion-between-rahul-gawale-and-koustubh).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The map in apex is always converted into a JS object when received in
> javascript. Each key of the map is converted
> to String before it passed to JS if its an object. That is why you were getting the values in this format `{label=Created By ID, value=Contact_ID__r.CreatedById}`

In my opinion, using an Object as the key will make your implementation very difficult to manage down the line.

So you need to use this format.

```
Map<String, Map<Stting,List<SelectOption>>
```

Where the key of the first map will be the object name like `Account`, `CustomObject__c`.

And, the key of the second (inner map) will be your field name.

---

Also as the standard SelectOption is not accessible in LWC, so you need to create a wrapper class for that like the below. You can define it as a separate class so it can be used across the org.

```
public class SelectOption {
    public SelectOption(String value, String label) {
        this.value = value;
        this.label = label;
        this.disabled = false;
    }

    @AuraEnabled
    public String label { get;set; }
    @AuraEnabled
    public String value { get;set; }
    @AuraEnabled
    public Boolean disabled { get;set; }// if needed in case
}
```